# gnome-text-editor always crashes because I opened a binary file with session restore enabled

Tags: gnome, gnome-text-editor

I've accidentally opened a binary file in `gnome-text-editor`, which caused the editor to hang. Since the session is restored, when I reopen the application, I cannot use `gnome-text-editor` anymore (it just always hangs).

I'm looking for the configuration or cache file so I can remove it or disable session reloading. Where can I find this?

Note that reinstalling the application did not help, neither did opening the application with any flag available in the help menu.

Edit;
Running on Ubuntu 22.10, version: 43.1-1ubuntu1, target: amd64, installed via apt

Comment: Always indicate the Ubuntu version in your question. If you are not using the default text editor in Ubuntu 22.10, indicate how you installed the app, via repository, snap or flatpack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The session state is stored in the file `~/.local/share/org.gnome.TextEditor/session.gvariant`. Removing that file will delete the current session state.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to disable restoring session via `gsettings`?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.TextEditor restore-session false
```

Comment: that does not work

Comment: first check if restore-session value is set to false via `gsettings get org.gnome.TextEditor restore-session`, then try to open some text file with gnome-text-editor on terminal and look for error messages.

Answer (score -2):

use the following command in terminal:

/usr/bin/gnome-text-editor -i

Comment: It would be a good idea to say why.

Comment: Unfortunately, non of the parameters to start a new session work